# regular expression issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i am getting the following regex from a json from server

```
regexval = ^[A-Za-z\\'\\s\\.\\-\\,]{1,50}$
```

there is a problem with this regular expression it has a ' which is breaking my js code to test this regular expression. how do i make this a valid regex?

im doing something like this to test it

```
if(!regexval.replace(/\\/g,"\\").test(inputVal)) {
}
```

**EDIT**

following is the JSON

```
[
    {
        "ExtensionData": {},
        "Data1": null,
        "DisplayName": "First Name",
        "IsRequired": true,
        "LengthValidation": 0,
        "Name": "ServiceFirstName",
        "RegexValidation": "^[A-Za-z\\'\\s\\.\\-\\,]{1,50}$",
        "Type": "String",
        "ValidationMessage": "The field 'First Name' doesn't meet the format requirements"
    },
 {
        "ExtensionData": {},
        "Data1": null,
        "DisplayName": "Last Name",
        "IsRequired": true,
        "LengthValidation": 0,
        "Name": "ServiceLastName",
        "RegexValidation": "^[A-Za-z\\'\\s\\.\\-\\,]{1,50}$",
        "Type": "String",
        "ValidationMessage": "The field 'Last Name' doesn't meet the format requirements"
    }
]
```

Comment: doing \\ in there will just cause your regex to look for literal backslashes (multiple times) and literal `'`, `s`, `.`, `-`, and `,`

Comment: so how do i make the regex valid? because !regexval.test(inputVal) is not working

Comment: is this object that json is passing in a string format to begin with?

Comment: `var regexval = /^[A-Za-z\'\s.\-,]{1,50}$/;`.

Comment: i have posted the Json please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the single quote to a unicode character `/u0027` or use the ASCII `\x27` and have it work properly?

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/TezdR/1/

SO, really you DON'T need to do the replace but can use the "string" as it is - here is an updated version where you can see I do the replace on FirstName but not on last - and they both should work the same:  http://jsfiddle.net/TezdR/2/

Comment: how do i change it all i have is the json from the webservice

Answer (score 3):

The double backslashes are evaluated to literal backslashes in RegEx notation... or escaped backslashes in a string (which then escapes the next character when evaluated as a regex).

The RegEx build solution is:

```
regexval=/^[A-Za-z\'\s\.\-\,]{1,50}$/
```

The string-build solution is:

```
regexval = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z\\'\\s\\.\\-\\,]{1,50}$");
```

Both of these produce a JavaScript [RegEx object](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/regexp.html) which you can then call `.test` etc on.

```
if (regexval.test(inputVal)) {
  //... do something
}
```

**Your Update**

Ok so per your update, if you parse that above structure into a local JS object called `jsonobj` (for example... how to parse etc I assume you know) and you want to just test the first entry in the JSON array returned... you'd need to do the following:

```
//jsonobj - JS object after parsing your example JSON above
var regex=new RegEx(jsonobj[0].RegexValidation);
if (regex.test(inputVal)) {
    //... do your work here
}
```

Comment: but still ^[A-Za-z\'\s\.\-\,]{1,50}$ is breaking i guess because of the ' what should i do? it says regexval.test is not a function

Answer (score 1):

```
regexval = /^[A-Za-z\\'\\s\\.\\-\\,]{1,50}$/
```

you're missing the /s needed to make it a regex value

and it looks like you actually need

```
regexval = /^[A-Za-z\'\s\.\-\,]{1,50}$/
```